# If X is polynomial reducible to Y and Y is in NP, is X in NP?

Tags: np

I need to know if this affermation is True, False or we can't know either

If X is  polynomial reducible to Y and Y is in NP, is X  in NP?

Comment: What do you think? Have you reasoned through the question yourself? What conclusions have you figured out?

Answer (score 1):

NP problems are defined as a class of decision problems for which we can verify a yes certificate in polynomial time.

If decision problem X is in NP, this means that a certificate for it can be verified in polynomial time. Given that X can be reduced to decision problem Y in polynomial time, this means that the verification of an answer to decision problem Y can also be performed in polynomial time. Since both the reduction and the verification are performed in polynomial time, then by definition Y is in NP as well.